# Angular, User authenticates on Login but does not route to dashboard. Removing AuthGuard works

Tags: angular, angular-routing, auth-guard

I am new to angular and spend around 2 to 3 hours online trying to navigate from login to dashboard if user authenticates. I am able to route to dashboard if I don't user canActivate: [AuthGuard]. However as soon as I add canActivate: [AuthGuard] I am stuck on the login page(though I see the user SignIn on firebase console). Its just not navigating me to dashboard page

My code..

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guard/auth.guard';
//import { SecureInnerPagesGuard } from "./shared/guard/secure-inner-pages.guard.ts.guard";
//import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './components/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path:  'sign-in',component:  SignInComponent},
  { path:  'dashboard', component:  DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from  '../../auth/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ){ }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
        this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
      }
      return true;
  }

}
```

I've also added [AuthGuard] in Providers of app.module.ts
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend no matter what to `return false` inside the `if` statement even with the navigate (https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your  if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) condition returns true and your app navigate to the route `sign-in`. check if the `this.authService.isLoggedIn` becomes true when your login success.

Also you don't need `if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true)` you can just use `if(!this.authService.isLoggedIn)`.

Comment: Thanks so much Hansaka, You pointed me in the right direction. I had created the user profile manually in firebase and in the isLoggedIn() method was looking for valid user and emailverified. So I never had verified email. I signed in with google and got sorted out. Also for signin with  email(without google) was still giving error which sorted out with your suggestion `if(!this.authService.isLoggedIn)` and that worked too. Thanks again